# Why do we use $Q$ for heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, notation, history

Of course letters are of few interest if something at all. But when reading some notes the question just appeared:

#### Why do we use $Q$ for heat?

Googling it shows many links but none of them seems convincent. Some say - including William B Jensen - $Q$ was related to *quantity*, but that seems rather silly. Maybe it will be convincent knowing about the context.

---

Some resources I checked:

[This work from William B Jensen](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed100769d)

[Wikipedia: notation an units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat)

Any idea?

Comment: What does William B Jensen say about it?

Comment: Says it's related to quantity, but no more information than that @sammygerbil

Comment: His suggestion is backed up by research. So it is a bit presumptuous to call it "silly". See http://www.che.uc.edu/jensen/w.%20b.%20jensen/reprints/182.%20q%20and%20q.pdf

Comment: I have read the paper @sammygerbil...What I mean is: given the info in Jensen paper, it seems silly for the scientist just to give a measurable quantity the name Q. But I'm not referring to Jensen!

Comment: If it has to be given a symbol, Q is as good as anything else.

Comment: @sammygerbil that's what I say in first sentence, but let me add something: the context of $Q$ is Work (W), Energy (E), P (pressure), V(volume). So, it was interesting to know. Just curiosity.

Comment: According to Jensen, Clapeyron used it to distinguish between what he called the quantity of heat ($Q$) and the intensity of heat (or temperature $T$). So it's a remnant of old terminology.

Comment: This should be moved to [hsm.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess:

[Quantite de chaleur](http://iupap.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/A4.pdf)

At that time the C was already used for capacitance *capacite thermique*, (same link) so Q was picked.

Thermodynamics and chemistry was strong in France. [Antoine Lavoisier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Lavoisier)

> He is widely considered in popular literature as the "father of modern chemistry".[3](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/j.1550-8528.1994.tb00646.x)[4]

...

> His first memoirs on this topic were read to the Academy of Sciences in 1777, but his most significant contribution to this field was made in the winter of 1782/1783 in association with Laplace.

In the ["memoir on heat"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/j.1550-8528.1994.tb00646.x)  , already the terminology is used and q is there, after heat being called "quantity of heat" , page 191. The original must have been in french.

Assigning symbols to physics quantities depends on the first people who used them a lot, and then convenience follows the serendipity. Look at radiation with the greek alphabet, alpha, beta, gamma . Then elementary particles kaon, lamda, mu, nu, xi , sigma , tau , phi,chi psi, omega. They were skipping the ones common to both alphabets, or used already generally, as pi. J/psi shows egos coming in :) .